# How create hibernate association by id?

Tags: java, hibernate, left-join

Here is a `Client` instance with `id` and `Order` instance with `clientId`. Is there a way to perform left join `Order` to `Client` without adding any fields for `Order`?
Result SQL shoul be like that:

```
 Select * from Client left join Order ON Order.clientId = Client.id
```

Note that `Order.clientId` may be null. Is there tricks to that with hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you add a One-To-Many relationship from Client to Order.

```
public class Client{

    @OneToMany
    private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();

    public List<Order> getOrders() {
       return orders;
    }
    public void setOrder(List<Order> orders){
       this.orders = orders;
    }
 }
```

Then do this :

```
EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT x FROM Client left join FETCH x.orders");
List<Client> clients = query.getResultList();
```